# Does C# support call-by-result?

Tags: c#, callbyname

I'm aware of 3 parameter evaluation types in C#:

1. default, which is by-value
2. ref, which is by-ref
3. out, which is by-ref but considered initially uninitialized and mandatory to assign

My professor stated that C# also supports by-result, which he explained as:

> 1. Argument has to be LHS-compatible
> 2. Create local copy of argument and operate on that
> 3. After successful processing of method body, write value of copy back to the parameter source

I don't see how this refers to any of the above types.

Comment: That and `ref` would produce the same result in both cases; maybe he got confused.

Comment: @false No, because ref updates the parameter source immediately, while this does only afterwards.

Comment: It sounds like your professor is talking about calls like this: `a = f(a)`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No, he was talking about 'regular' calls (e.g. `int i = 1; f(i);` now i is 2)

Comment: Maybe lambda with captures? Like `Action<int> f = v => i = 2*v; f(i);`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Possibly - could you add this an a complete answer? If I understand your example right then it does work here. Even though I'd think that he did not intend to use the functional paradigm here, he would technically be correct then!

Comment: @mafu: Er, sorry, I meant “most” rather than “both”.

Comment: you can make that work only with params that are not objects (simple values or structs)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - no, it does not.

Comment: I think so, too, but I would need a little more proof ;)

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative. Let the professor prove that it _does_.

Comment: Yes, I'll ask him next time, but I was hoping for something along the lines of the language spec

Comment: This is why I hated the school. So much unnecessary theories and occasionally false information.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not clear what teacher meant, it is possible to get code that *textually match* something like

```
 int i = 1; f(i); //now i is 2
```

by using lambda expression that captures local variable.

```
int i = 1;
Action<int> f = v => i = 2 * v; 
f(i); 
Console.WriteLine(i); // now i is 2
```

Note that `i` in call to `f` is passed strictly "by value". It could be as well `f(42)` - parameter does not have any impact on what variable will be changed as result of execution.

Answer (score 2):

No, not an explicit C# language feature.  It does not suffer from major aliasing problems, the kind that are common when a language only supports pass-by-reference or has pointers as a first-order language feature.  And very little syntax to make threading easier, beyond the *lock* keyword.

One rule in C# that helps is that it forbids passing a property by reference, a problem that can only be solved by call-by-result.  Notable is that VB.NET doesn't have this rule and solves it by implementing call-by-result automatically.  This does have a knack for [causing surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632610/in-visual-studio-is-it-possible-and-how-to-make-vb-net-compiler-handles-the).

It does occur in practice on a MarshalByRefObject that lives in another execution context.  Like another AppDomain or another machine.  Necessarily so, a *ref* argument needs to be copied across the context boundary before the call and copied back afterwards.  This is however largely transparent to the program, not counting a quirk that requires [applying the [Out] attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9073985/17034) explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your professor might be referring to plain variable reassignment upon method completion (i.e. `i = DoSomething(i)`), or possibly operators which result in variable reassignment under the covers, i.e. `++`.

To illustrate this:

```
class Immutable
{
    public readonly int Value;

    public Immutable(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static Immutable operator ++(Immutable obj)
    {
        return new Immutable(obj.Value + 1);
    }
}
```

Now we can do the following:

```
Immutable a = new Immutable(1);
Immutable originalA = a;

Debug.Assert(a.Value == 1);
Debug.Assert(a == originalA); // Same instance (obviously).

a++;

Debug.Assert(a.Value == 2);
Debug.Assert(a != originalA); // New instance.
```

This appears to satisfy all criteria:

- You *can* perform LHS assignment on a variable of type `Immutable`.
- The operator method receives a *copy* of the original variable (you can reassign `obj` inside the body of the method, it won't affect the original location).
- `a` is reassigned once the operator has finished executing, and will point to the newly-created instance.

**EDIT**

While this is definitely not the answer as it does not satisfy any of the points, I think it's worth mentioning that you can also get the "by ref" semantics by passing around pointers, which I am sure everyone knows. What some may not know, however, is that this can also be done using `TypedReference`, which is a special beast in MS C#:

```
void DodgyIncrement()
{
    int i = 0;

    this.Increment(__makeref(i));

    Debug.Assert(i == 1);
}

void Increment(TypedReference i)
{
    __refvalue(i, int) += 1;
}
```